# Loop through several post hoc tests in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, anova, tukey

I have a dataframe called data. I have created a function that loop thorugh a list of variables and creates a linear model for each of them using lapply. This method is based on [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm) post.

```
library(datasets)
testDF <- data.frame(Salaries)
#creates list of variables

varListTest <- names(testDF)[3:4] 

#creates a model for each of the variables in question
model<- lapply(varListTest, function(x) {
    lm(substitute(i~Rank, list(i = as.name(x))), data = testDF)}) 

#output model
lapply(model, summary)
```

This works great. However, I would also like to run post-hoc tests in the same fashion, normally i would do this by running:

```
TukeyHSD(model)
```

This obviously won't work in this example, but I thought this would:

```
lapply(model, TukeyHSD)
```

But this returns:

```
no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "lm"
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Can you give some data using `dput(data)`.

Comment: yes, so I'm not so comfortable uploading my own data here, so I changed my post to include a sample dataset from R.  The output of dput(testDF) is posted here: https://codedump.io/share/TKO5BlEbPgSF/1

Comment: Guy, your code has even more problems= `varList` defined and `varList`used, `Anova` that does not exist (`A`..), please test your own code...

Comment: right, okay so fixed (and tested) the code again. Anova requires a different package, I've changed that to summary, which is in the r base

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
lapply(model, function(m) TukeyHSD(aov(m)))
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
testDF=iris


varListTest <- names(testDF)[1:3] 

#creates a model for each of the variables in question
model<- lapply(varListTest, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(i~Species, list(i = as.name(x))), data = testDF)})  


lapply(model, function(model) TukeyHSD(aov(model)))
```

Which provide (truncated)

```
[[1]]
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = model)

$Species
                      diff       lwr       upr p adj
versicolor-setosa    0.930 0.6862273 1.1737727     0
virginica-setosa     1.582 1.3382273 1.8257727     0
virginica-versicolor 0.652 0.4082273 0.8957727     0
```

Comment: perfect! just what I wanted! Thanks alot.