# output of variable names in looped Tukey test

Tags: loops, variables, posthoc, tukey

I'm doing multiple TukeyHSD tests by looping through all dependent variable names as in the code provided by Eric Lecoutre in this thread:

[Loop through several post hoc tests in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270373/loop-through-several-post-hoc-tests-in-r)

It works very well, so thanks Eric! But in the output the variable names are written as numbers: [[**1**]] for the first variable, [[**2**]] for the second variable, ...[[**137**]] for the 137th variable, etc.

How can I change these numbers into the variable names in the output (so that I can capture the output into a file and preserve the information about the variable names in the output file)?

Specifically, in the output from Eric Lecoutre's answer:

[[**1**]]

Tukey multiple comparisons of means

```
95% family-wise confidence level
```

Fit: aov(formula = model)

For example, if the names of the 2 dependent variables for the loop are "sepal.width" and "sepal.length", I want to change [[**1**]] of the output into [[**sepal.width**]], [[**2**]] of the output into [[**sepal.length**]].

How can I make the script to loop through the numbers and change the numbers into the variable names so that the output appears like this (*I omitted the statistical results to simplify the output*):

[[**sepal.width**]]

Tukey multiple comparisons of means

```
95% family-wise confidence level
```

Fit: aov(formula = model)

[[**sepal.length**]]

Tukey multiple comparisons of means

```
95% family-wise confidence level
```

Fit: aov(formula = model)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well specified, but from what I understand you want to change the list object names. The list object names can be gathered with `names(your_list)`, for ex.

`abc=list(x=cars[,1],y=cars[,2])`
`names(abc)`
`[1] "x" "y"`

and of course change them at will with

`names(abc)=c("exx","why")`

Comment: Sorry that my question isn't clear. I have edited it now and hope it's more specific. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: But the variable names are already inside the data frame, i.e. they are column names. However, the output of the Tukey test does not preserve the variable names (or column names); instead it changes the variable names into numbers 1, 2, etc. So, how should I change Eric's code to make the Tukey output automatically print the variable names (or column names) instead of printing numbers?

Comment: Take a look at the `USE.NAMES` argument from the lapply function.

Comment: Thank you! I did some searches and saw that using sapply with the argument USE.NAMES=TRUE preserves the variable names in the output. lapply does not have USE.NAMES option. So I changed lapply to sapply in the codes. Problem solved.